# Send mail to different recipients via Outlook using a single macro

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

[image]I'm fairly new to VBA. 
I've figured a way to send a mail picking up content from the table and sending it to the desired recipient using a macro.

Now, I need to send mails with different content to multiple recipients, all the required data is present in the same table, with the recipient name being one of the columns. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim StrBody As String
Dim LastRow As Long

StrBody = "Hi," & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
"The following Talents were last reporting to you and have now moved to bench. Please confirm the plans. " & "<br><br>"

With Worksheets("To-Bench")
LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

Set rng = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
'For Only the visible cells in the selection
'Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
'For fixed range 

Set rng = Sheets("To-Bench").Range("A1:G2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
'Hardcoded the number of rows which is actually indefinite'
  On Error GoTo 0

If rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
           vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next



With OutMail

    'Application.Goto ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(6, 5)
    .To = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 9).Text   'I've hardcoded the recipient as of now'
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Movement of " & Range("C2").Value & " Talents to Bench"
    .HTMLBody = StrBody & rangetoHTML(rng)
    .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub

Function rangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2013
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
rangetoHTML = ts.readall
ts.Close
rangetoHTML = Replace(rangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Some additional notes, the data will be picked up from a table where multiple rows will have the same recipient. Is there also a way to combine all the data corresponding to the recipient and send it within a single mail?

Comment: Can you share image of the spreadsheet?

Comment: *send mails with different content to multiple recipients* meaning you are sending different email body to multiple recipients (they can know who else on list)? You can use To, or BCC. What you try to achieve is doable, but missing critical logic in the post. I guess you will be using a loop to loop through the rows for the content, then different loop for the recipient?

Comment: @PatricK Multiple recipients as in, single recipient for multiple e-mails to be generated by the single macro.

Comment: @0m3r Done. Here, if two rows have the same 'PM' (recipient), then their data should be combined and sent in a single mail.

Comment: You may consider turning the range into a Table, then use filter and loop thru each unique recipient for their assigned part, then copy paste the visible range into email. Or create individual emails about each row of the filtered data.

Comment: @PatricK I'm having trouble getting around understanding how to implement it, thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution from Ron deBruin.

In column A : Names of the people
In column B : E-mail addresses
In column C:Z : Filenames like this C:\Data\Book2.xls (don't have to be Excel files)

The Macro will loop through each row in "Sheet1" and if there is a E-mail address in column B
and file name(s) in column C:Z it will create a mail with this information and send it.

```
Sub Send_Files()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FileCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each cell In sh.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
        Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("C1:Z1")

        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With OutMail
                .to = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Testfile"
                .Body = "Hi " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value

                For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                    If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                        If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                            .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                        End If
                    End If
                Next FileCell

                .Send  'Or use .Display
            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

    Set OutApp = Nothing
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

If you need to merge several cells into a single cell, you can concatenate a range using the following method.

```
Function ConcRange(ByRef myRange As Range, Optional ByVal Seperator As String = ";")

ConcRange = vbNullString

Dim rngCell As Range

For Each rngCell In myRange
    If ConcRange = vbNullString Then
        If Not rngCell.Value = vbNullString Then
            ConcRange = CStr(rngCell.Value)
        End If
    Else
        If Not rngCell.Value = vbNullString Then
            ConcRange = ConcRange & Seperator & CStr(rngCell.Value)
        End If
    End If
Next rngCell


End Function
```

Comment: My e-mail recipients can be common for several rows, I need to combine all the corresponding data to a unique recipient into one mail.